# botão com duas funções jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, funções

Estou tentando colocar duas funções no mesmo botão.

To pegando o botão pelo ID e chamando a função de click que joga a nav-bar pro footer da página e também chama a outra função que se clicar no toogle de novo joga a nav-bar pro topo novamente. mas não sei fazer um loop entre essas duas funções.

```
$(function(){

$('#toogle').click(function(){
    $('nav').css('marginTop', '720px')
    navTop()
})

function navTop() {
    $('#toogle').click(function(){
        $('nav').css('marginTop', '0')
    })
}
```

});

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button id="toogle" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

Comment: E pra quê criar duas funções? Só precisa de uma função e alguma condição que verifique se está está top, se está joga pro bottom, se bottom joga pro top. Simples assim.

Answer (score -3):

Talhez não entendi direito, porém, vou tentar dar uma ajuda.

```
um = ()=>{
alert("Chamou primeira")
}

dois = ()=>{
alert("Chamou segunda")
}

$("btn_one").click(()=>{
um()
dois()
})
```

//Observe que o evento de clique deve estar abaixo das duas funções (um, dois), pois quando o botão for clicado, o JavasScript irá chamar uma função que foi carregada em cima da função que captura o clique.

Comment: Observe que seu código estar errado porque divertiu de como eu explique, pois perceba que você está tentando chamar uma função  (navTop) que ainda não foi carregada, pois ela está abaixo da função que a chama (navBottom).